# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined with babel + browserify

Tags: javascript, webpack, gulp, browserify, babeljs

I get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

**I know that in the browser you can not use require API**, just trying to make it possible with browserify or requirejs or whatelse but it doesn't work in any way.

This is my gulpfile

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    plumber = require('gulp-plumber'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var babel = require('gulp-babel');
var browserify = require('gulp-browserify');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    cache = require('gulp-cache');
var minifycss = require('gulp-minify-css');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
  browserSync({
    server: {
       baseDir: "./"
    }
  });
});

gulp.task('bs-reload', function () {
  browserSync.reload();
});

gulp.task('images', function(){
  gulp.src('src/images/**/*')
    .pipe(cache(imagemin({ optimizationLevel: 3, progressive: true, interlaced: true })))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/images/'));
});

gulp.task('styles', function(){
  gulp.src(['src/styles/**/*.scss'])
    .pipe(plumber({
      errorHandler: function (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
        this.emit('end');
    }}))
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 versions'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/styles/'))
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(minifycss())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/styles/'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream:true}))
});

gulp.task('scripts', function(){
  return gulp.src('src/scripts/**/*.js')
    .pipe(plumber({
      errorHandler: function (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
        this.emit('end');
    }}))
    .pipe(concat('main.js'))
    .pipe(babel())
    .pipe(browserify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/scripts/'))
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/scripts/'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream:true}))
});

gulp.task('default', ['browser-sync'], function(){
  gulp.watch("src/styles/**/*.scss", ['styles']);
  gulp.watch("src/scripts/**/*.js", ['scripts']);
  gulp.watch("*.html", ['bs-reload']);
});
```

and this is my main.js, just an import of a plugin anime.js

```
import anime from 'animejs'
```

Also tried with requireJs but it seems a bit hard to integrate it in my gulpfile, also webpack seems to be hard code for me.